# CloudWatch metric filter custom metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I created custom metric based on this documentation using CloudWatch Metric Filter. However, the error count data points are not accumulated. All the data points are shown as a straight line on the graph.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountOccurrencesExample.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected average for the metric to view.

Select "sum of" statistics for the given time range and you can see the accumulated value.

If you still don't see the accumulated value, I would do a check whether you are posting those custom metrics with the right value and log them. Value goes on Dimension, not at the root.

Custom Metrics NameSpace --> Metric Name, Value should be in cloudwatch metric values.

Comment: Can you please share what was the issue you had? Since there are more than on failure that could happen.

Comment: I changed average to sum and I see total count of errors.